# Get dynamically assgined IP/port from Marathon inside containers

Tags: ip, port, containers, mesos, marathon

I have an application that deploys through *Marathon* multiple similar servers (containerized in *Docker* containers), using Marathon auto-assigning 'port' feature. That is nice and excatly the way I need in my app.

The problem is that my servers deployed in Marathon ([PyWPS](https://github.com/geopython/pywps) servers) are using code that does not fit really well with modern distributed architecture. PyWPS requests to define into a static config file, the IP and Port for the polling from the client apps.

When I have static IP/ports on my containers, it is easy to run a script (inside the container) at the launch of the container that 'sed' the config file to put the right IP/port values from a ENVVAR that I set in the container starting command line.

The problem arise when it comes to use undeterministic dynamic IP/port. 
Is there a way to catch these info in the container when it is deployed by Marathon, as a kind of **event "container_start"** hook ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this should be easily solvable in a similar way as you described.

For example, if you run your app with HOST networking and a random port (by specifying `"ports": [0]` for example), then Marathon will set the `$HOST` and `$PORT0` environment variables. You don't need to set something similar in a manual way.

Then, have your entrypoint script manipulate the configuration based on these two environment variables, and you should have a fully dynamic ip/port setting.

Comment: Thank you Tobi for your anwser.
I finally patched my servers code since it was more straightforward in my case. but your solution would work as well.

Comment: @matt Can you explain a bit? In what way did you apply the patch?

Comment: [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214454/dynamic-ips-for-polling-and-results-requests-using-pywps) is the way I've patched PyWPS in order to get the wanted behaviour